# Как получить айди упомянутого юзера (@nickname)

Tags: python, telebot

Пытаюсь сделать команду `/check` и упоминание  пользователя (@username), которая будет выдавать айди этого человека, его юзернейм и то что он написал, но никак не могу найти функцию которая это всё может вычислить. Помогите плиз

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PS. Работает только с юзерами у которых нет юзернейма

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['check'])
def check_user_id(message: types.Message):
    for entity in message.entities:
        if entity.to_dict().get('user'):
            bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text=f"{entity.user.id}")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: привет, у меня не работает, просто ничего не происходит. в консоле тоже ничего нет
скопировл всё точно так же (если что мой бот на хостинге repit)

Comment: [если что вот весь мой код в боте](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1knzNRSS9N5jxD2XgWLL5yCavICXtN-NZ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Попробуйте запустить без сервера

Comment: попробовал, всё точно так же. мб библиотеки какие то дополнительные нужны?
либо в botfatherе что то настроить

Comment: Сделайте в хендлере принт, и посмотрите будет ли он срабатывать

Comment: добавил принт после каждой функции.
принт перестаёт писаться после for entity in message.entities:
дальше ничего не пишется.     
код `@bot.message_handler(commands=['check'])
def check_user_id(message: types.Message):
    print("до def check_user_id(message: types.Message):")
    for entity in message.entities:
        print("до for entity in message.entities:")
        if entity.to_dict().get('user'):
            print("до if entity.to_dict().get('user'):")
            bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text=f"{entity.user.id}")
            print("Конец")`

Comment: Крч мой способ работает только с теми у кого нет юзернейма а только номер

Comment: К слову других способов я не нашёл. Скорее всего их и нет. Нельзя используя только bot api сделать то что вы хотите

Comment: окей... а на aiogram возможно это сделать?

Comment: если нет - попрошу вас показать ещё библиотеки для телеграм ботов, а если да - попрошу вас скинуть код для этого

Comment: Нет, это невозможно для ботов. Может юзер бот сможет, но я хз

Comment: эхх, ну ладно. Тогда пожалуйста, скиньте код того же самого что и раньше, но с помощью reply.

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: ну типо, /check вместе с ответом на сообщение другого человека. которое будет отображать информацию о нем (не о МНЕ, а о авторе сообщения в ответе)

Comment: просто `message.reply_to_message.from_user.id`

Comment: спасибо! а как сделать чтобы на inline кнопку мог нажать только определённый человек?

Comment: `if messge.from_user.id == ...` ?